# How To Save Attachments object to RackSpace Cloud using C#?

Tags: c#, file, cloud, rackspace

I Have one 'System.Net.Mail.Attachment[] attachment' object , This object contains PDF,Xls,Doc or jpg file.

I want to save this attachment object to cloud server.

```
string sSavePath = "EmailAttachment/" + intSomeid + "/";
  string strErrorMsg = string.Empty;

 if ((attachments != null))
                            {
    MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
    StreamWriter memoryWriter = new StreamWriter(memoryStream);
    memoryWriter.Write(attachments[0]);
    memoryStream.Position = 0;
    CloudFileSystem.SaveFileToCloudSystem(memoryStream, ref strErrorMsg, sSavePath, ConfigHelper.PrivateContainer, attachments[intI].Name);
    memoryWriter.Dispose();
    memoryStream.Dispose();
}
```

I have used the above code to save the file.
The File is saved to cloud but having 0 Byte data (Corrupted) File.
I have searched many places for that.
But not able to find error in the code.

Please suggest some solution in this case ?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you are making it yourself more difficult then needed. The `Attachment` instance has an [`ContentStream`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.attachmentbase.contentstream(v=vs.100).aspx) property which you don't need to feed through a MemoryStream at all.

```
string sSavePath = "EmailAttachment/" + intSomeid + "/";
string strErrorMsg = string.Empty;

if ((attachments != null))
{
   CloudFileSystem.SaveFileToCloudSystem(
     attachments[intI].ContentStream, 
     ref strErrorMsg, 
     sSavePath, 
     ConfigHelper.PrivateContainer, 
     attachments[intI].Name);
}
```

If you are doing this:

```
MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
StreamWriter memoryWriter = new StreamWriter(memoryStream);
memoryWriter.Write(attachments[0]);
```

You are probably writing the string representation of `Attachment` (ToString() gets called) and that is not the content of your file.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. 'attachments[intI].ContentStream' is what i have tried initially. this is also saving file with 0B. So issue is not gettting resolved with that. Please help me further

Answer (score 0):

After so much r&d ,I have come up with the following answer

Memory stream of attachment object didn't work for me.
So I have approached temp path where the attachement was saved and do the following magical code :

```
string FileName = ((System.IO.FileStream (attachments[intI].ContentStream)).Name;
MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
using (FileStream file = new FileStream(FileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
{
byte[] bytes = new byte[file.Length];
file.Read(bytes, 0, (int)file.Length);
ms.Write(bytes, 0, (int)file.Length);
}
ms.Position = 0;

CloudFileSystem.SaveFileToCloudSystem(ms, ref strErrorMsg, sSavePath, ConfigHelper.PrivateContainer, attachments[intI].Name);
ms.Dispose();
```

I hope my question and answer helps you for your project